# seaborn violinplot out of valid range

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, violin-plot

I am using seaborn to create violin plots. Right now I am creating violin plots out of proportion values (so all values are between 0 and 1), but the resulting violin plot is quite off.  Its bottom ranges into negative values and its top ranges into values greater than 1. Below is an example which I ran to test it:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
y = np.asarray([.1725,.1825,.163,.1625,.93,.943,.893,.93,.11225,.93,.812,.832,.9425,.953,.8525,.993,.963,.1425,.113,.752])
x = np.asarray([1]*len(data))
sns.violinplot(x=x,y=y)
sns.plt.show()
```

Clearly none of the values are outside of the range [0,1], yet the violin plot looks all screwy:

[Violin plot that is out of range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNGWu.png)

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is due to the shape being estimated by a kernel density estimator. It does not know that values are constrained between 0 and 1. To get a proper understanding, you may want to familiarize yourself with kernel density estimation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28119908/419338

Comment: Ah excellent, I wasn't aware of what I was looking for. Thanks for this!