# Seaborn Overfitting Violin Plots

Tags: python, distribution, seaborn, violin-plot

I am wanting to use a violin plot to compare a distribtuion of scores from two different dates. The scores are a percentage, yet for some reason the plot results in values greater than 1 and less than 0 despite the fact that all scores lie between 0% and 100%. The code includes a for loop because I am repeating this across multiple cases.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ell68.png)

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45dVn.png)

Comment: This link might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115637/how-to-better-fit-seaborn-violinplots/28119908#28119908

Answer (score 1):

Specify `cut=0` to cut off the KDE outside min/max values in your sample.